# Why this binary search implementation causes overflow?

Tags: algorithm, overflow, binary-search

In the implementation of binary search

```
int search(int[] A, int K) {
  int l = 0;
  int u = A.length - 1;
  int m
  while ( l <= u ) {
     m = (l+u)/2; // why this can cause overflow
     ...
  }
}
```

The correct method is as follows:

```
m = l + (u -l )/2;
```

I don't know why the updated statement has no overflow issue. Based on my understanding,
soon or later, the updated statement will also have overflow issue.

Comment: could you explain how the updated statement overflows

Comment: don't you mean: m = (l + (u -l ))/2; ?

Comment: @Yochai: No, because that would just be u/2. His calculation is correct (although the loop condition is not).

Comment: yea, didn't notice that. it's late lol

Comment: @David, originally, I assume that the l and u can start with a overflowed number. But I think we should not make that assumption. -- thx

Comment: @q0987 By definition, the values that l and u can hold are not overflowed. It's the values that they can't hold that are overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orignal may have overflow because `l+u` could be greater than the maximum value an `int` can handle (e.g. if both `l` and `u` were `INT_MAX` then their sum would obviously exceed `INT_MAX`).

The correct method can't overflow, because `u-l` obviously won't overflow, and `l+(u-l)/2` is guaranteed to be `<=u`, so can't overflow either.

Comment: @Yochai: You can't do that, because if l=3 and u=5, m = l/2 + u/2 = 1 + 2 = 3, but you want m = 4.

Answer (score 0):

The initial Calculation of `m = (l+u)/2`  create overflow due to addition of very large numbers.
So, Difference of these numbers does not cause this overflow condition ,that's why we are calculating `m=l+(u-l)/2` using this formula.